# What does 'ref' keyword do in the case of assigning ref return type to ref paramater

Tags: c#, ref

Consider the following example:

```
public ref T GetComponent<T>() where T : struct, IComponentData
{
    return ref componentAnymapReference.GetComponent<T>(Entity).ComponentData;
}

public bool TryGetComponent<T>(ref T componentData) where T : struct, IComponentData
{
    if (!Entity.HasComponent<T>())
        return false;

    componentData = ref GetComponent<T>();
    return true;
}
```

The line `componentData = ref GetComponent<T>();` also compiles like `componentData = GetComponent<T>();` without any errors or warnings.

What does `ref` do in this context? Why would it be needed, any why may it be ommited?

Comment: please see my updated answer that addresses your question about the difference between `componentData = ref GetComponent<T>()` and `componentData = GetComponent<T>();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning a `ref` type is the converse of accepting a `ref` parameter. You are returning a reference to a specific variable; whoever is given that reference can modify that variable directly.

Consider this example:

```
class Person
{
    string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        init => _name = value;
    }

    public ref string GetNameRef()
    {
        return ref _name;
    }

    public static void Example()
    {
        var person = new Person { Name = "Joe" };

        string normalReturn = person.Name;
        normalReturn = "New Name";
        Console.WriteLine($"Person Name = {person.Name}");  // expecting "Joe"

        ref string refReturn = ref person.GetNameRef();
        refReturn = "New Name";
        Console.WriteLine($"Person Name = {person.Name}");  // expecting "New Name"
    }
}
```

Modifying `refReturn` allows you to change the private value of `Person._name`. A normal return would just return an instance of the same string as `_name` but would not give you the ability to change `_name` otherwise.

The use cases for this are admittedly limited, if not dubious. My example, though illustrative, is unrealistic of course. I imagine this has more uses in more functional programming styles rather than OOP where objects are largely expected to manage their own state.

One situation I imagine this could be useful is if a method took a number of `ref` parameters as inputs and returned one of them depending on some condition. For example:

```
    public static ref int MaxRef (ref int a, ref int b)
    {
        if (a >= b)
            return ref a;
        else 
            return ref b;
    }

    public static void Example2()
    {
        int a = 10;
        int b = 20;

        ref int max = ref MaxRef(ref a, ref b);
        max += 10;  
        Console.WriteLine($"b={b}"); // expect 30
    }
```

---

Investigating the OP's specific question of the difference between

```
 componentData = ref GetComponent<T>(); // (a)
```

and

```
 componentData = GetComponent<T>(); // (b)
```

leads to a curious result.

(a) causes `componentData` - the parameter - to refer to an entirely different variable than before. Basically it will do nothing, as written. The original variable `componentData` `ref`ed will not be impacted as `componentData` no longer points to it.

(b) (without the `ref` in the assignment) will lead to what is likely the expected result, which is that the variable `ref`ed by `componentData` will now have the value returned by `GetComponent<T>`.

While this is confusing because `ref` is used in C# as both the indirection and the address-of operator, depending on context, it makes sense if you wrote the same code in quasi C++:

```
// public ref T GetComponent<T>() 
public T* GetComponent<T>() 
{
    // return ref componentAnymapReference.GetComponent<T>.ComponentData;
    return &(componentAnymapReference.GetComponent<T>.ComponentData);
}

// public bool TryGetComponent<T>(ref T componentData) where T : struct, IComponentData
public bool TryGetComponent<T>(T* componentData) 
{    
    // componentData = ref GetComponent<T>(); 
    componentData = GetComponent<T>();  // changes the local value of componentData, which basically does nothing

    // --or--

    // componentData = GetComponent<T>();
    *componentData = *GetComponent<T>();  // more likely what you want
    return true;
}
```

And for an example that clearly illustrates this, building on my prior example:

```
    public static void Example2()
    {
        int a = 10;
        int b = 20;
        int max = 0, max2 = 0;

        GetMax1(ref a, ref b, ref max);
        Debug.WriteLine($"max={max}");   // max is chagned by GetMax1 (without the ref)

        GetMax2(ref a, ref b, ref max2);
        Debug.WriteLine($"max2={max2}");   // max2 isn't changed by GetMax2 (with the ref)
    }

    private static void GetMax1(ref int a, ref int b, ref int max)
    {
        max = MaxRef(ref a, ref b);
    }

    private static void GetMax2(ref int a, ref int b, ref int max)
    {
        max = ref MaxRef(ref a, ref b);
    }
```

Note that there's no way to get `max2` to ultimately become a `ref` of `b` by passing it in as a parameter to `GetMax2`. This would require GetMax2 to take a `ref ref int max` parameter, which isn't allowed (though it is in C++). So in your example, if you were hoping to wind up with a `ref` of the underlying variable returned by `GetComponent<T>`, that's not possible - the best you can do is assign the variable `ref`ed by `componentData` a copy of the `struct`.

As a total aside, using interfaces with `struct`s gets you around all this. Casting a struct instance to its interface type is equivalent of taking the address and casting the interface reference to its struct type is equivalent of dereferencing the pointer.

Comment: That's great, could you also explain the difference between the two when the variable being given the ref/normal value is itself a ref paramater?

Comment: _"A normal return would just give you a copy of the string."_ - no, it would not.

Comment: @GuruStron of course it would. What are you getting at?

Comment: `string` is a reference type and creating a copy of arbitrary length string on every return would be a performance nightmare. You can easily prove that returned instance of the string would be the same either via reflection or unsafe string modification.

Comment: @GuruStron ok that's obviously not what I meant. Of course a normal return gives you a copy of *the reference* to that specific string but doesn't allow you to change the original variable.

Comment: While it can be obvious to you and me it can be not that clear to everyone. Also again - you can change "original variable" via unsafe API and in case of "ordinary" (non-immitable one) reference type the difference would be a bit more subtle.

Comment: _"I imagine this has more uses in more functional programming styles rather than OOP"_ - this has nothing to do with functional programming, even more - I would argue that in contradicts the FP principles which favors immutable data structures and avoids mutations. In my experience usually `ref`'s are used for performance reasons.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252930/discussion-between-just-answer-the-question-and-guru-stron).